# ktor with ConditionalHeaders & HttpCache plugin does not return 304 NOT MODIFIED on second request

Tags: ktor, ktor-client

I have installed `ConditionalHeaders` plugin on my server instance together with the `HttpCache` plugin (just in-memory cache) on the client.

and it seems that ktor handles the extraction of the `ETag` header and using it for the subsequent request as the `If-None-Match` header automatically.

At least by juding by the test case below, the request object does carry the expected value.

But the problem is that the second request returns `200 OK` instead of the expected `304 NOT MODIFIED`. Am I misunderstanding something?

When I debug this and put some breakpoints in `EntityTagVersion.check(..)` method the first request returns `VersionCheckResult.OK`, but the second request does return `VersionCheckResult.NOT_MODIFIED`.. however the status codes is still `200 OK`

I made this test-case to illustrate the issue:

- code here https://github.com/sphrak/ktor/pull/1/files

```kotlin
@Test
fun testIfNoneMatchConditionAcceptedAlt(): Unit = testApplication {

    val client = createClient {
        install(HttpCache)
    }

    val text = """the answer is 42"""

    application {
        routing {
            route("a") {
                install(ConditionalHeaders) {
                    version { _, outgoingContent ->
                        if (outgoingContent is TextContent) {
                            listOf(EntityTagVersion(etag = outgoingContent.text.encodeBase64(), weak = false))
                        } else emptyList()
                    }
                }
                get("b") {
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, text)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val first = client.get("a/b")
    assertEquals(expected = text.encodeBase64().quote(), actual = first.etag())
    assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, first.status)
    assertEquals(text, first.bodyAsText())

    val second = client.get("a/b")
    assertEquals(expected = first.etag(), actual = second.request.headers[HttpHeaders.IfNoneMatch])
    assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.NotModified, second.status)
    assertEquals("", second.bodyAsText())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server replies with the `304 Not modified` status code on the second request. However, the `HttpCache` plugin substitutes it with the `200 OK` response from the cache, so the second actual response from the server cannot be observed externally.

Comment: ah that explains it, so it is in fact actually working then. Thank you for clarifying